# Get an object instance from FieldInfo

Tags: c#, reflection

So my problem is this: I have an object instance represented only by FieldInfo. I have no other access to that object. Is it possible to get that object instance only through the field info like so?

```
MyObject myObject = fieldInfo.SomeMethodOrProperty as MyObject;
```

This is just only an illustration, but I think you get the picture.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the `FieldInfo` represents attributes and metadata of a field in regards to a type. It is not attached to a specific instance. When you want to use it, you have to pass in the instance you want it to use (through [`GetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee433930.aspx) or [`SetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee436193.aspx))

Answer (score 3):

**Despite the other answer saying no, this is possible.**
I had the same problem and after some test I found this code to work:

```
Type oType = typeof(MyClass);
FieldInfo[] aoFieldInfo = oType.GetFields (BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);

foreach (FieldInfo oFieldInfo in aoFieldInfo)
{
  object oValue = oFieldInfo.GetValue (null);
}
```

and it returns the values / objects of all members, of which I previously queried the `FieldInfo`.

Answer (score 1):

I know this old but yes it is possible as long as you can have access to the instance of the parent object of the object in question...

for example:

```
public AxisObject getAxisObjectByName(string name)
    {
        FieldInfo[] Comboproperties = typeof(DrivesObject).GetFields();
        foreach (var property in Comboproperties)
        {
            if (property.Name == name)
            {
                return (AxisObject)property.GetValue(PersistantVariables.Instance.Drives);//pass the instance you're wanting to return child object instance from
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I too was searching for this answer, found some inspiration in Tobias Knauss's answer.

Hopefully this helps someone as well.

With my fields placed in this Holiday class, I wanted to access them all in a collection.

```
    class Holiday
    {
        public static readonly DateTime New_Years_Day = new DateTime(year: DateTime.Now.AddYears(1).Year, month: 1, day: 1);
        public static readonly DateTime Christmas_Day = new DateTime(year: DateTime.Now.Year, month: 12, day: 24);
        public static readonly DateTime Thanksgiving_Day = new DateTime(year: DateTime.Now.Year, month: 11, day: 25);
        public static readonly DateTime Labor_Day = new DateTime(year: DateTime.Now.Year, month: 9, day: 6);
        public static readonly DateTime Memorial_Day = new DateTime(year: DateTime.Now.Year, month: 5, day: 31);
                                                                      

}
```

To test I created a method to run my test:

```
    static DateTime[] get_all_holidays()
    {  
        DateTime[] _holidays = 
            typeof(Holiday)
            .GetFields()
            .Select(s => 
                (DateTime)s.GetValue(null))
                .ToArray(); 

        foreach (DateTime holiday in _holidays)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(holiday.ToString());

        }

        return _holidays;
    }
```

When I run the above code, I check my locals and see all the dates.
[image]

And finally implemented into a property for quick access:

```
    public static DateTime[] All_Holidays {
        get {
            return 
                typeof(Holiday)
                    .GetFields()
                    .Select(s =>
                        (DateTime)s.GetValue(null))
                        .ToArray();
        } }
```