# Get Object Instances from FieldInfo

Tags: c#

I'm trying to call a method for each of the variables/instances of a given type in my class. I've found other posts describing a way to do this using reflection. However, the examples I have found are using `Activator.CreateInstance()` or with only one instance of the given class (using `FieldInfo.GetValue()`). I would like to call this method on the instances themselves, rather than creating a new instance and calling the method. Is this possible?

Example of what I'm trying to do:

```
public class Data
{
    int x;
    public Data(int x){
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    private Data instance1 = new Data(5);
    private Data instance2 = new Data(4);

    ...

    public void PrintAllX(){

        var fields = GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).Where(f => f.FieldType == typeof(Data));
        foreach(FieldInfo field in fields)
        {
            MethodInfo method = field.FieldType.GetMethod("Print");
            var instance = ?;// need to get 'Data' instance for each field here (instance1, instance2)
            method?.Invoke(instance, null);
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried setting instance equal to `field.GetValue(null)` for this as suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44872191/20914725), but it did not work giving me the error: `TargetException: Non-static field requires a target`.

Comment: Think about it... `field.GetValue(null)` is like saying `null.theField` without reflection.

Comment: The only way to *call a method for each of the variables/instances of a given type in my class* is to maintain a collection of them somewhere and iterate through it.  .NET doesn't maintain one for you.

Comment: Pay attention to the flags used in the linked answer (and why `null` works there): it has `BindingFlags.Static`, whereas you have `BindingFlags.Instance`.

Comment: Okay thanks for that, @dbc and madreflection . I was hoping there was some way to do this for my non-static fields of my class (and avoid needing to create a list of these fields). I saw it was possible for static fields: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70039958/20914725. However, with the error I'm receiving I suppose it's not possible for non-static.

Comment: You don't need to maintain a collection, although it makes things run faster on subsequent calls. `var instance = field.GetValue(this);` and you're good. `GetType()` is getting `typeof(MyClass)` (why not use that, though?), so the fields need an instance of `MyClass`, and `this` is exactly that in that context. Metaprogramming at 1x level requires 10x closer scrutiny on what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [madreflection's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74987479/get-object-instances-from-fieldinfo#comment132330679_74987479) I was able to come up with a solution for my problem. Here's the solution to the example code from my question. Note that as mentioned in his comment, using a collection may be better for subsequent calls. However, in my case I am only ever calling this method once so the performance of subsequent calls isn't a problem.

```
public void PrintAllX()
    {

        List<object> fieldObjs = GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).Select(s => s.GetValue(this)).ToList();
        foreach (object obj in fieldObjs)
        {
            if (obj == null) continue;

            if (obj.GetType() == typeof(Data))
                ((Data)obj).Print();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am missing something.. but reflection may not be the right tool here.

Instead of making each of your `Data` fields separate variables, what if you put them in a collection.. then you can avoid reflection entirely.

Something like:

```
public class MyClass {
    private Data instance1 = new Data(5);
    private Data instance2 = new Data(4);

    private List<Data> datas = new List<Data> {
        instance1,
        instance2    // etc...
    };

    public void PrintAllX() {
        foreach(Data data in datas) {
            data.Print();
        }
    }
}
```

Update: modified code to be a hybrid - field variables, with a List of those field variables.

Comment: My reason for not doing this was because in my actual code I have properties in MyClass referencing the specific values/instances of the Data class (i.e. public int X1 => instance1.X * some other value). Using a list in this case would make it a bit of a pain to write those properties, as I would have to know specifically which index instance1 is stored in (or search for it).

Comment: @Sayon: updated code to demonstrate how to have the best of both.  You can make your list members be references to your field objects.